# Why mkfifo'ed pipe only updates after ~25 seconds?

Tags: linux, named-pipes, mkfifo

I have one program writing to mkfifo created device 7 lines of text data every 3 seconds using `printf()`. I am trying to read it with `cat /path/to/device` in another terminal window. But instead of updating every 3 seconds, it will print something only once every 25 seconds. Why? How to make it update faster? (Ubuntu Wily)

Comment: are you using concurrency with other shells scripts ?

Answer (score 1):

One or both ends of the pipe is buffering more than you want.  In your writing program, `fflush` when you finish writing your 7 lines, and read the output with `cat -u` (if your `cat` is not GNU cat).